# Sorting a cell array in matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting

I have an array of `81x1 cell` of `str`. which looks like this, 
`'1.png'`
`'2.png'`
`'100.png'`
`'43.png'`
`'20.png'`
`'32.png'`
`'98.png'`
and so on. 
I am trying to sort it using the sort function. 
`sort(A)`
but it doesnt sort it. what should I do?

Comment: what is the result of your sort() function?

Comment: have you looked at [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/90698-how-do-i-sort-cell-array)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `.png` using [`regexprep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) or [`strrep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html), convert the remaining [string to double](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) and then use [`sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) to get the sorted indices. Use these sorted indices to sort the cell `A`.

```
[~, ind] = sort(str2double(regexprep(A,'.png','')));
A = A(ind);
```